# Display data in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I need to display only name from `request` in my form, can't figure out how to do it. I'm just starting with js, need help.

I have tried this `{{ request.name }}` but doesn't work. `{{request}}` shows me full data.

```
const app = new Vue({
      el:'#valuation-request',
      data() {
        return {
          step:1,
          request:{
            name:null,
            industry:'{{ $company->industry }}',
            valuation_date:null,
            similar_comp:null,
            total_raised:null,
            sales_transactions:null
          }
        }
      },
      methods:{
        prev() {
          this.step--;
        },
        next() {
          this.step++;
        }


      }
    });
```

Comment: `name` is null so it's not going to print anything. Are you setting it's value somewhere else?

Comment: I'm setting it in form <input type="text" class="uk-input" name="name" v-model="request.name" id="name" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" required>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `name` has a value, it should display as you wrote it. If it's null, nothing will be displayed.

```js
const app = new Vue({
      el:'#valuation-request',
      data() {
        return {
          step:1,
          request:{
            name: null,
            industry:'{{ $company->industry }}',
            valuation_date:null,
            similar_comp:null,
            total_raised:null,
            sales_transactions:null
          }
        }
      },
      methods:{
        prev() {
          this.step--;
        },
        next() {
          this.step++;
        }


      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="valuation-request">
  {{request.name}}
  <hr>
  Name: <input type="text" class="uk-input" name="name" v-model="request.name" id="name" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" required>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm setting name in form <input type="text" class="uk-input" name="name" v-model="request.name" id="name" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" required>

Comment: @PhilippNoris I don't see the issue. Note the change to the example above.

Comment: I found the problem :) Thanks!